# Toilet Tank slow leak, have all new parts, tried all troubleshooting...help!

Tags: leak, toilet

Just installed the Fluidmaster 400ARHRK (http://www.fluidmaster.com/our-products/toilet-fill-valves-toilet-parts/400arhrkp10-performaxr-all-in-one-toilet-repair-kit.html) and we still have a slow leak of about 1/2" in the tank. Can't figure it out. The water in the tank drops about 1/2" maybe every hour or so. The tank refills to the proper level. Then it will drop again 1/2". Repeat.

You can see the discrepancy in the water level in the photo below, the tank has lost water about 1/2".

When I shut off the water supply to the tank the tank looses more water but doesn't empty.

There are no leaks onto the floor, on the outside of the tank or anything like that.

There is plenty of slack in the the flapper chain. Flapper fits snugly. The kit came with a new rubber gasket as well.

I saw this on another forum, which is what we are experiencing: "If it drains down to a certain point and stops, then you have the small refill tube stuck too far down into the overflow pipe." But in our case the refill tube sits above the overflow pipe - see photo below.

We don't see any pieces of the old flapper or any "debris" that could be stuck somewhere to cause the tank to lose water. We are thinking of disassembling and starting over but can't see that helping.

Any ideas??

[image]

Not sure if this makes any difference, I turned off the water supply from the house to the tank this morning and at lunch the tank is totally dry. Does this help me at all?

So I know the water is leaking into the bowl and not the floor/outside the tank.

Should I still do the dye test? Will that pinpoint where the leak is occurring (flapper, overflow pipe, seal beneath flapper)? Or does the dye test just show you it's leaking into the bowl (which I already know)?

They sell a seal of sorts I see that you put on top of the thing that the flapper lid (I think) closes down on that is supposed to maybe help flapper leaks. Should I get this?

I just know if I will be able to determine from where the leak is occurring...?

Comment: Just to make sure...  You took the tank off of the bowl, and installed every single part that kit comes with?

Comment: Yes. We did all that.

Comment: can you hear any leaking? Does it appear to be leaking into the toilet bowl (for instance, it flushes itself eventually)?

Comment: I don't hear any leaking. I am not aware that it "flushes itself," ever. 1/2" water gets lost, then the tank refills. And water will come out of refill tube into overflow pipe/flush valve. The tank water level is correct again. Until it looses 1/2" water. Then it repeats. If it leaks into the toilet bowl it's very slow - but I guess that's where the water is going since it's not on the floor...?

Comment: Put a few drops of food coloring in the tank water, then wait.  See if the bowl water changes color.  Then make sure the flapper is seated properly.

Comment: Haven't done the dye test...yet, but we have inspected the new flapper and as far as we can tell it's fitted properly, snugly, correctly. If dye goes into bowl then it MUST be flapper leak? What if there is no dye in the bowl? Where else could water go, if not the bowl or outside of tank (which it's not)?

Comment: I'm curious if the issue has been resolved? What was written here is EXACTLY what has happened to me. I've tried adjusting the water level up and down, can't hear or see any leaking, even replaced the brand new flapper right out of the kit with another brand new flapper I bought, no luck. I actually didn't have a large enough wrench to tighten the large plastic locknut onto the flush valve (directions said "hand tighten locknut and then use large adjustable pliers to go 1/2 turn beyond hand tight"), so I'm wondering if that's it? Any further comments would be much appreciated.

Comment: "I just know if I will be able to determine from where the leak is occurring...?"  Turn off the water and let the water leak down until it stops leaking.  The leak will be at that level.

Answer (score 4):

If your tank is constantly leaking water, but you've not found it anywhere, then it is nigh on certain that it's going into the toilet bowl. Tester101's tip of putting food colouring into the tank and seeing if it appears in the bowl will likely confirm this.

The issue is then to find exactly where the leak is. Either your flapper isn't closing properly, there's a leaky joint where the overflow pipe connects (just below the flapper), or the seal between the flapper apparatus and the tank isn't watertight.

I would hazard a guess at it being the seal between the flapper apparatus and the tank, probably due to either under-tightening or over-tightening when installing the new flush. Over-tightening is perhaps the more likely - it shouldn't be tightened too much or you will distort the rubber seal.

Comment: OK, we will check the seal "tightness," I think that's one thing we haven't readjusted. TY

Comment: +1 for mentioning the over tightening, it is fairly common for the flush valve seat to become warped due to age and/or over tightening if the large hex nut, preventing a good seal even with a brand new flapper.